# Extracting a function from a Contour Plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, approximation

**Context to understand the question**

Suppose that I have the next equation

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
```

And I make a Contour Plot of this equation

```
 ContourPlot[y[a][x] /. sol, {x, 0, 0.1}, {a, 0, 4},PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,LegendMarkerSize -> 180,   LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMargins -> 5, LegendLabel -> "y[a][x]"], Frame -> True,  FrameLabel -> {{"a", ""}, {"x", ""}}, BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 14}]
```

[image]

Next I obtain a specific line of this ContourPlot

```
ContourPlot[y[a][x] /. sol, {x, 0, 0.1}, {a, 0, 4}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"a", ""}, {"x", ""}},  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 14}, 
Contours -> {1.15}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

**Quesiton**

Is there an "easy" way to obtain an equation  for the red line, I mean the function $a(x)$?

I need the  function, to make calculations, for example  $(a(x))^{1/2}$.

**"Long" way to obtain the equation for the red line**

I usually take a image of the the graph and use [webplotdigitizer](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/) to extrac the points of the graph and after  I aproximate the extracted points with a polinominal function, however this prodedure can be slow.

Comment: A contour is just a level set, also known as an isoline - a curve where $f(x) = c$ for some value $c$. If you can solve that equation you can parametrize the curve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you may not know is that the notebook interface is a bit like a web browser. Whatever complicated interface the web browser is showing, you can always just right-click and show the HTML source code for it. It's not delivered as a bunch of pixels, and similarly, graphics (to be distinguished from actual images, including rasterized graphics) are just expressions. Consequently, you don't need to use a third-part tool to get the coordinates of the line. Just do it like this:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}];
cp = ContourPlot[y[a][x] /. sol, {x, 0, 0.1}, {a, 0, 4}, Contours -> {1.15}];
line = First@Cases[Normal[cp], _Line, Infinity];
```

Visualizing it to make sure it's working:

```
Graphics[{line}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.1}, {0, 4}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Output]

It seems like you already have a way forward from this point with polynomial fitting that you have done previously.

`Normal` is needed because in the expression generated by `ContourPlot`, the line coordinates are encoded with `GraphicsComplex`. I use `Normal` to replace the coordinate indices with the actual coordinates.

I might also add that the functionality offered by the third-party tool you mention seems to be similar to a function already built into Mathematica. You can right-click the graphics in Mathematica and click "get coordinates". You can then left-click on a couple of points along the line and press ctrl+c to copy the points to clipboard. Now you can paste that data into another cell.

Comment: Really impresive solution. However there is something that I don't understand, how I can I get "line" as a function of "x"?  In the past when I need to make manipulations I just use the function $a[x]$,  for example if I do $2*a[0.1]$ I get a number, I tried with $2*line[0.1]$, but doesn't work.

Comment: @Cruz I’m not showing that part. `Line` is a graphics primitive. You can turn it into a list using `List @@`. You can use `Interpolation` or whatever to get a function, or as I said in my answer, the polynomial fitting approach that you’ve used so far should also be possible to use with these coordinates. I focused on getting the coordinates, since that seemed to be the main problem.

Comment: Thank you, is one of the problems. But I was looking for the function.

Comment: @Cruz ok, then I recommend `Interpolation`.

Comment: `{minx, maxx} = MinMax[line[[1]][[All, 1]]];
func = Interpolation[Midpoint /@ Partition[line[[1]], 2, 1]];
Plot[func[x], {x, minx, maxx}]` - it's up to you if you want to use the `Midpoint`s of the lines that make up the curve - you could also choose points on the end of the line. Or you could even get points randomly like `RandomPoint[line,1000]` and then fit a curve.

Answer (score 6):

For this specific case the exact solution can be found.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1};

sol = DSolve[eqns, y, t][[1]]

(* {y -> Function[{t}, E^(a t)]} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
eqns /. sol

(* {True, True} *)

a[x_, const_] = a /. Solve[(y[x] /. sol) == const, a][[1]] /. C[1] -> 0

(* Log[const]/x *)

With[{const = 1.15},
 Plot[a[x, const], {x, 0, 0.1},
  PlotRange -> {0, 4},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, a})]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My method is uglier than just extracting a spline like with C. E's answer. It's possible find points on this contour with an `NMinimize` and use an `Interpolation` to get the curve as a function of $x$ (see `func` below):

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}];
fn = y /. sol;

(* Set the target contour *)
target = 1.15;

(* For each value of 'a' find 'x' that minimizes square error of fn[a][x] to target *)
minpoints = Table[
  {x /. Last[NMinimize[{(fn[a][x] - target)^2, 0 < x < 0.1}, x]], a}, {a, 0, 4, .1}
];

(* Choose the best {x,a} solution points closest (within 10^-6) to the target value *)
filteredMinpoints = Select[minpoints, Abs[fn[#[[2]]][#[[1]]] - target] < 10^-6 &];

(* Interpolate this curve - this is now a function of 'x' we can use later *)
func = Interpolation[filteredMinpoints];
Show[
 ContourPlot[y[a][x] /. sol, {x, 0, 0.1}, {a, 0, 4}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 180, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMargins -> 5, 
    LegendLabel -> "y[a][x]"], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"a", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 14}],

 (* Show a plot of the curve we interpolated *)
 Plot[Quiet@func[x], {x, 0, .1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
]
```

[image: contour curve]

Comment: I have two questions. First, why this solution is computaninaly  "slow"?

And second, when you compile your code it says "InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {2.04286*10^-6} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used." what is the meaning of this?

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't know if is too much. But I really want to understand why you use "fn = y /. sol", is incorrect if I do "fn[x_]:=y[x] /. sol"?

Comment: 1) It's slow because it's doing a minimization for every point. If you want a fast method use the analytic solution with `DSolve` or extract the spline from the plot. I'm leaving this method here because it's an alternative when `DSolve` isn't feasible. 2) At the edges it's plotting an interpolation beyond the points I gave it, so it needs to extrapolate. 3) I use `fn = y /. sol` because your original `ParametricNDSolve` returns a rule `y -> ...`.